# SQL: combining results from join table into one field in a query

Tags: sql

I haven't been doing any queries at work for several months because of a new project I was put on so I'm completely spacing on how to do the following:

I have one table named "eJournals", a second named "providerJoins", and a third named "providers".

The fields are as follows:

eJournals

1. eJournalID
2. Title

providerJoins

1. joinID
2. providerID
3. eJournalID

providers

1. providerID
2. providerName

My question is this, what needs to happen in the query to get something like this:

```
eJournalID      Title         providerName
1               blah          providerblah
2               blah2         providerblah2
3               blah3         providerblah3
etc....
```

I'm sure the solution will make me hit my head and say, "oh yeah, duh" but... like I said, I haven't been using sql in months.

Comment: What is the relationship between eJournals and providerJoins? is it joinID = eJournalID?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the link between the tables... providerJoins has eJournalID in it.  eJournals.eJournalID = providerJoins.eJournalID and providerJoins.providerID = providers.providerID.

Comment: please edit your question - you didn't mention the joins in the tables, nor did you mention that you want more than multiple providers to be concatenated into one row...

Comment: Also, what DB are you using? which version?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
SELECT J.eJournalID, J.Title, P.ProviderName FROM eJournals J
        JOIN ProviderJoins PJ ON PJ.eJournalID = J.eJournalID
        JOIN Providers P ON P.ProviderId = PJ.ProviderID
```

Comment: Nope, listed multiple results for each eJournal if they had more than one provider :(

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was more than a 1:1 mapping. If there are say, three different providers for one ejournalId, how should those be displayed?

Comment: @Brds: What would you want done when the journal has multiple providers? Choose one provider? Concatenate all the providers together in one column?

Comment: @Birds Unfortunately I haven't found a very 'pretty' way of concating columns in SQL. Hopefully someone else can give you some help.

Comment: I would recommend using another general-purpose programming language to combine providers for each journal into a list. That would be more like custom report creation than simple SQL query. My language of choice - Python ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.eJournalID, e.Title, p.providerName
FROM eJournals e
INNER JOIN providerJoins j ON j.joinID = e.eJournalID
INNER JOIN providers p ON p.providerID = j.providerID
```

That ought to do it

Comment: The relationship field is not joinID - its eJournalID.

Comment: I think this is wrong; the j.joinId doesn't have a relationship to the eJournals table.

Comment: fair point, updated. while i was writing I assumed naming convention had been followed. Totally spaced on `providerName`!

Comment: n.title?  You don't define n anywhere and i'm not sure where you're going with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some field relationship between eJournals and providersJoins table to make this work - otherwise there is no way to say which providerName goes with which eJournal.

Given that the relationship is eJournalID, the below should work...

```
select e.eJournalID, e.Title, p.providerName
from eJournals e, providerJoins pj, providers p
where e.eJournalID = pj.eJournalID
and pj.providerID = p.providerID
```

Comment: old school :) I still think its much more readable than INNER JOINS

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this?

```
SELECT 
    e.eJournalID,
    e.Title,
    p.ProviderName
FROM
    eJournals e
    INNER JOIN providerJoins pj ON e.eJournalID = pj.eJournalId
    INNER JOIN providers p ON pj.providerId = p.providerId
```

Comment: Still lists out each journal several times if they have several providers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eJournalID, e.Title, p.providerName
FROM eJournals AS e JOIN providerJoins AS pj ON e.eJournalID = pj.eJournalID
JOIN providers AS p ON pj.providerID = p.providerID
```

Note: "DISTINCT" should remove any duplicate rows in the results.

Comment: Lots of similar answers here :-). SQL is popular!

Comment: Just like the others, returns several results for the same ejournal.

Comment: I added "DISTINCT" to the query, does that help remove your duplicates? Would need to see the result you're getting if that doesn't help.

Comment: Nah, they're technically different b/c they have different providerNames... so the distinct makes no changes.

Comment: Please show an example of the result you're getting vs the result you're trying to get. If the providerNames are different then they will show up in separate (distinct) rows for the result.